# Looping through two vectors in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to loop through two vectors that are using the same base class. See the example below.

```
for (const Animal *animal : [LOOP THROUGH TWO VECTORS HERE] ) {
    // access animal functions / variables
}
```

In the example above I try to loop through two vectors of animals. One vector is `const Alpaca*` and the other is a `const Llama*` (both are animals).

Comment: What are your vectors? In what order do you want to loop through them (synchronized, one after the other, interleaved, ...) ?

Comment: Are they the same size?

Comment: Why do you want it to be one loop if there are two vectors? You could create a new vector with `const Animal*` and copy both vectors into the new vector.

Comment: There's nothing in C++ that will do this for you. Either loop through each vector individually or create your own custom iterator class; but this is likely something that's currently way too advanced task, for you. Eventually as your C++ expertise increases you'll be able to create your own iterator classes with custom semantics like that, which will simply allow you to write code like that. But it takes time to learn C++ to reach that point.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for your comment. So there's nothing (simple) I can do to make the following code more efficient: https://pastebin.com/0dTHYr4r

Comment: The only thing you can do is factor out the duplicated logic into a helper class, or a lambda, in order to remove the duplicated code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**boost::combine**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/combine.html)

[**Here is a sample**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fa8RIexGleqKGhGs):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main()
{ 
    std::vector<int> a = {1,2};
    std::vector<char> b = {'a','b'};
    int c;
    char d;
    for (auto v :  boost::combine(a, b) ) {;
        boost::tie(c, d) = v;
        std::cout << c << " " << d << " ";
    }
}
```

Output

```
1 a 2 b
```

You can also take a look at [**std::merge**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge)

Comment: Wow, this is so new to me. Thanks for sharing! Will this work for any number of vectors? Will it also work for any container?

Comment: Though this answer might be impressive for at least two people - IMHO, it's not what the OP is looking for. OP stated that two vectors shall be iterated sequentially (one after the other without pairing the values of both together).

Comment: @Scheff If that's the case then the OP could simply use two loops one after the other, what's the point of combining them then?

Comment: @ArdentCoder With two loops, you have to duplicate the loop body (or move it to a lambda).

Comment: @ArdentCoder IMHO like suspected by Sam: to eliminate code duplication.

Comment: @Scheff, thanks for the feedback, I can't see that requirement in OP's question.

Comment: This solution forces a extra dependency(boost) on OP. And a nasty one at that. It also prevent OP from learning ( using two loops and calling a function or using a lambda, or many other nice technique to learn)

Comment: @Scheff I get it, but nobody has replied to my first comment yet

Comment: @ArdentCoder Yepp, I noticed this. But, the OPs link to pastebin looks like Sam was on the right trace... (to me). ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Ah I saw that now. That link and the phrasing of the question seems very different! Someone should edit that question in order to avoid this confusion. As of now, this boost approach satisfies [LOOP THROUGH TWO VECTORS HERE].

Comment: @ArdentCoder, sorry didn't see your question, it works for any container, you can also use different containers in the same loop, e.g. lists, basic arrays, vectors, etc. Boost iterator library is very good.

Comment: @anastaciu That's cool. Will that work for user-defined containers as well? Which functions should be overloaded within the class to support this functionality? I'm sorry if this should not be a comment but a separate question :P

Comment: @ArdentCoder, the provided link has the function template and use conditions, and yes, I reckon it would be a good question.

Comment: @anastaciu Haha, I haven't asked more questions here because of immediate downvotes lol. Let me try with this one because I can't completely understand the contents of that link, I'm still a student :P

Comment: @ArdentCoder, that can happen, to better your changes don't ask a generic question, provide a sample of your own, like a container made by you and then try to combine with different containers, and present the results of your tests, I think when you're done you might not even need to ask the question anymore. A good, complete question is not something easy make.

Comment: @anastaciu Thanks for your suggestions :) I will try that when I can get into a computer, the electrician isn't coming to repair the switchboard anytime soon :( Until then I can feel some downvotes coming along the way lol

Comment: @ArdentCoder, lol, if you go for it, you can count with my UV.

Answer (score 2):

Just use two loops, and put processing in a function:

```
void f(Animal* animal)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

...

```
for (const Animal *animal : alpacas ) 
{
    f(animal);
}
for (const Animal *animal : llamas ) 
{
    f(animal);
}
```