# Conditions to use boost::combine

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, containers

I saw boost::combine being used to iterate over two vectors simultaneously inside a single for loop in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60739925/10251345).

I have some questions regarding that:

1. Will that work for any container?
2. Will that work for any number of containers?
3. Is boost::combine used for anything else?